# Deal with duration in Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, duration, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a script for a spreadsheet with Google script. But I have a problem with durations.

More precisely, I have a file with 30000 lines or so, and I would like to skim it according to certain criteria.
First, if a certain value is non zero, then I delete the row. And then, I have to input a starting duration, an ending duration and minimum and maximum values for this interval.
Afterwards, I'd like to loop through the values in this duration interval and delete everything not in the range defined above.

The first part is pretty easy and was done without any problem. 
For the second part though, I can't figure out how to input a duration in the same format as the duration displayed in the file.

My file has duration with format [hh]":"mm":"ss but when I try to input duration with this format, It displays

```
[01]:00:00
```

if I input  `25:00:00`

Here is what I have so far:

```
function removeFromInterval() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("D1");
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt(
  'Création des valeurs de configuration',
  'Entrez le temps minimum',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

// Process the user's response.
var button = result.getSelectedButton();
var text = result.getResponseText();
if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
  // User clicked "OK".
  var value = new Date(text)
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(value, 'GMT+1', '[hh]:mm:ss');
  display(date);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error log?

Comment: There is no error, just I can't work out how to have my durations in the right format.

Comment: That is the excepted behavior, 25:00:00(hh:mm:ss) => there is no 25 hour in a day, hence 25 is converted to 01 hrs. Similarly, 24 => 0hrs, 26 =>2hrs Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this to set your format

```
 function removeFromInterval() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D1");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
  'Création des valeurs de configuration',
  'Entrez le temps minimum',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); 

   var button = result.getSelectedButton();
   var text = result.getResponseText();
    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
     range.setValue(text)                    // set the value of the cell D1 to the text you input
     range.setNumberFormat("[hh]:mm:ss")     //set the format of the cell to format you desire
    }
}
```

as for reason your input `25:00:00` gets converted to `[01]:00:00` is because there is no 25 hr in a day, so 25 gets converted to 1hrs. Date is not same as duration.

Hope that helps

Comment: I understand why it became 01, but I wanted to know how to set the format as duration, I will try your code.